# Django - delete recently created objects across database

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, sql-delete

Is there a way to delete like, all the objects that have been created in the last 10 mins across all the models? Or atleast across 1 model? Unfortunately, I am not storing any created field in those models.

Database - Postgresql

Comment: It's not possible as no datetime data available. But if you want delete last 5/10 or something else data it's possible

Comment: @shafik It's in thousands. I had a bulk_create inside a loop :(

Comment: without datetime field how can we compare ?

Comment: If you assume in last 10 minutes 500/1000 data inserted then it can be deleted. But it's dangerous for production database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django id's are auto-incrementing. So, if we know the id of the last object created before the problem, we can simply do -

```
Model.objects.filter(id__gt=last_id).delete()
```

It is not the ideal solution, but works for now.